# Broadcom Macbook Pro 2010 elementary OS 7 Horus

Tags: wifi

Can someone direct me to where to get Broadcom kernel that is on the elementary OS 7 Horus iso? It's locked and I can't access it to install. The driver does work in "Trial boot," but is not available after eos is installed and as I said can't be syphoned from the USB install stick as it's locked. I have tried several options through terminal to no avail.